# Qooxdoo 3.0.1 error: Overwriting generated property method of Class is not allowed

Tags: qooxdoo

I 'm new in qooxdoo especially qooxdoo 3.0. I just tried to migrate my web apps from qooxdoo 2.1.2 to recent version 3.0.1. But i got some error and my apps can't run well.

One of the errors is : Overwriting generated property method of Class is not allowed!

Please explain me why what about this error and how to fix it. And why it's displayed when i migrate, but not at my old version?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

qooxdoo has a build in property system [1] which automatically creates accessor / mutator functions for properties. These methods can not be found in the source code but are still available for the developer. As they won't show up in the source code, it can easily happen that a developer override such a method e.g. from a superclass. Let's say you extend the from qx.ui.basic.Atom and add a member method named 'getLabel'. That method would shadow the original / automatically create 'getLabel' which is usually not on intension. As qooxdoo doesn't have any infrastructure to support such overrides on intention, an error will be thrown to signal a potential error in the code. This bug report [2] has more details on that topic.

- [1] http://manual.qooxdoo.org/current/pages/core/understanding_properties.html
- [2] http://bugzilla.qooxdoo.org/show_bug.cgi?id=4726